# Is it mandatory to provide meta tags for rich snippets?

Tags: html, meta, schema.org, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

I'm using rich snippet in my website. Example: Consider providing `Organization` schema.

Is it necessary to provide `<meta property="name" content="something />` or is it enough to provide `<div property="name">something</div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conforming RDFa parser will parse the whole document and take all RDFa statements into account, no matter if it’s an element in the `head` or in the `body`, no matter if it’s a `meta` or a `div` element.

These three snippets should generate the same RDF:

```html
<html>
  <head typeof="schema:Organization">
    <title>Example 1: meta in the head</title>
    <meta property="schema:name" content="Foobar" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example 2: meta in the body</title>
  </head>
  <body typeof="schema:Organization">
    <meta property="schema:name" content="Foobar" />
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example 3: div in the body</title>
  </head>
  <body typeof="schema:Organization">
    <div property="schema:name">Foobar</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool often has some quirks, though; it might not necessarily conform to RDFa all the time. For example, it seems that Google doesn’t recognize types specified on the `html` element. If you are interested in Google’s Rich Snippets/Cards, simply check your markup in the SDTT to see how it gets interpreted by Google: if your data is part of the output, you are probably fine.)